# How get URL of specific airflow DAG run/execution?

Tags: airflow

I am using call back function if DAG succeeds or fails. I can get the url of the DAG but I need to get the URL of the specific DAG execution so I can provide that link in the callback functions which sends a notification.

The format of the URL to the graph view is:
`...graph?dag_id=<DAG_ID>&execution_date=<execution_date>`

Is there built-in variable/function to get that URL when I define the DAG?

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer is:

```py
def on_failure_callback(context):
    dag_id = context["dag"].dag_id
    execution_date = context["execution_date"].isoformat()
    print(f"http://0.0.0.0:8000/base/graph?dag_id={dag_id}&root=&execution_date={execution_date}")
```

However, it requires you to adjust base url and port (can be done by accessing `airflow.conf`).

There's a built in function [build_airflow_url_with_query](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/79494a6f9ef491a1accdcc178e7434eb456e74da/airflow/utils/helpers.py#L210-L218) but it requires app context which does not exist during invoking callback and will result in error.

Comment: This works! I I have to encode the execution_date using urllib something like `urllib.parse.quote(execution_date)`

Comment: Nice, it's possible than the `url_for` flask method which is used in mentioned method do this too.

Comment: `from airflow.configuration import conf ... conf.get('webserver', 'base_url')` works for me

Answer (score 2):

Full code

```
def on_failure_callback(context):
    import urllib.parse
    base_url = context['conf'].get('webserver', 'BASE_URL')
    dag_run = context["dag_run"]
    execution_date = urllib.parse.quote(dag_run.execution_date.isoformat())
    dag_url = f'{base_url}/graph?dag_id={dag_run.dag_id}&root=&execution_date={execution_date}'
```